# Sending mail with Pony and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, forms, email, sinatra, pony

I am trying to send an email from a contact form (built in HTML) with the Pony Gem within sinatra, I have followed the docs but something must be missing.

This is the Pony config

```
 get '/contact' do
  erb :contact, :layout => :layout
 end

 post '/contact' do
 require 'pony'
 Pony.mail({
:from => params[:name],
    :to => 'myemailaddress',
    :subject => params[:name] + "has contacted you via the Website",
    :body => params[:comment],
    :via => :smtp,
    :via_options => {
     :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
     :port                 => '587',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true,
     :user_name            => 'myemailaddress',
     :password             => 'mypassword',
     :authentication       => :plain, 
     :domain               => "localhost.localdomain" 
     }
    })
    redirect '/success' 
   end


   get('/success') do
@notification = "Thanks for your email. I'll be in touch soon."
erb :index, :layout => :layout
   end
```

So after clicking submit the contact page gets re rendered with no message

here is my submit button

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn" value="send">Submit</button>
```

Am i missing a trigger here somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the form setup to do a `post`?  If it seems to be refreshing the page the `form` tag may not be setup properly.  Also the button to submit should be an `input` tag of type `submit`.  The HTML would need to look something like this:

```
<form action="/contact" method="post">
   <!-- your form elements go here -->

   <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

Comment: you where right, silly error on my part not setting the action and post...Now it doesnt like:subject => params[:name] + "has contacted you via Website", it is throwing a nil class error regarding the +

Comment: Hmm.  Seems like `params[:name]` could be `nil`.  Make sure a form element with `name` set to `name`.  Like so: `<input name="name" type="text">`.

Also, if you want to prevent the `nil` pointer error regardless, you can do something like this `:subject => "#{params[:name] || 'Someone'} has contacted you via the Website"`.  That will make it default to `Someone` if the `name` parameter is not passed in.

Comment: thats exactly what it was i had type = text, id = name, got mixed up there, thanks again

Comment: All HTTP forms are automatically assumed to be `method='POST'` if the attribute is not specified. Forms will also POST to the same url if it's not specified, which makes defining routes a lot easier too.